# Right meaning of the phrase

Tags: meaning

> [man] makes himself the instrument of somebody or something outside of
>   himself; **he need not solve** the problem of living by productive
>   activity.

Bold part means “a man doesn't need to solve any problems”, not “a man have no problems to solve”? Is it common phrase?

Comment: _he need not_ means the same thing as _he doesn't need to_, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Yes. Could you post that as answer?

Comment: Hmm.  The way the politics work on this site, I think I'd rather you clarify your question first.  Then I'll think about it, and possibly post it as a more expanded answer.

Comment: What can I do to clarify question?